# It is possible to get a binary array from a BinData::Record instance?

Tags: ruby, binary, bindata

I'm using Ruby gem [Bindata](https://github.com/dmendel/bindata), using the following code:

```
require 'bindata'

class Rectangle < BinData::Record
  endian :little
  uint16 :len
  string :name, :read_length => :len
  uint32 :width
  uint32 :height
end

rectangle = rectangle.new
rectangle.len = 12
```

It is possible to get from `rectangle` instance an array like `[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, ...]` with the binary representation of all the fields inside the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`BinData::Base#to_binary_s`](http://rubydoc.info/github/dmendel/bindata/master/BinData/Base#to_binary_s-instance_method) returns *"the string representation of this data object"*:

```
rectangle.to_binary_s
#=> "\f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
```

This can be converted to a bit string via [`String#unpack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-unpack):

```
rectangle.to_binary_s.unpack('b*')
#=> ["00110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]
```

Or to a bit array via:

```
rectangle.to_binary_s.unpack('b*')[0].chars.map(&:to_i)
#=> [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```